# getItems isn't working in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have installed a Magento Product Parts Interactive Diagram Extension in Magento CE 1.8.1.0.

The issue is it only renders one single Part Diagram per product. I need it to render all Diagrams for each product.

The code is :

```
public function getPartDiagram()
    {
        if ($this->getId()) {
            return Mage::getModel('pws_productpartsdiagram/productpartsdiagram')->load($this->getId());
        }

        if (Mage::registry('product')) {
            $collection = Mage::getModel('pws_productpartsdiagram/productpartsdiagram')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('sku', Mage::registry('product')->getSku());
            return $collection->getFirstItem();
        }

    return null;
}
```

If I `return $collection->getLastItem();` it works and the last item is rendered on the front-end as expected.

But I cannot seem to get all items rendered, `getItems` does not work.

The code file is as follows, not sure but it might help.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Catalog product parts list block
 *
 * @category   PWS
 * @package    ProductPartsDiagram
 * @author     Anda Bardeanu <info@pandawebstudio.com>
 */

class PWS_ProductPartsDiagram_Block_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    protected $_productsCount = null;

    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 5;

    protected $_columnCount = 4;

    protected $_items;

    protected $_itemCollection;

    protected $_itemLimits = array();

    /**
     * Initialize block's cache
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('empty', 6)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('one_column', 5)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('two_columns_left', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('two_columns_right', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('three_columns', 3);

        $this->addData(array(
            'cache_lifetime'    => 86400,
            'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG),
        ));

        if (!$this->getData('template')) {
            $this->setTemplate('pws_productpartsdiagram/list.phtml');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        return array(
           'CATALOG_PRODUCT_PARTS_'.$this->getPartDiagram()->getId(),
           Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
           Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
           Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
           Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
           'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
           $this->getProductsCount()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection with new products and applied page limits.
     *
     * return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $partDiagramId = -1;
        $partDiagram = $this->getPartDiagram();

        if ($partDiagram) {
            $partDiagramId = $partDiagram->getId();
        }

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $resource      = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $productsTable = $resource->getTableName('pws_productpartsdiagram_products');

        // no pagination
        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter();
            //->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
            //->setCurPage(1);

        $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinInner(
                    array('_table_products' => $productsTable),
                    '_table_products.product_id = e.entity_id',
                    array()
                )
            ->from("", array('partdidagram_product_id'))
            ->where('_table_products.partdiagram_id = '. (int) $partDiagramId);


        $this->setProductCollection($collection);

        $this->_itemCollection = $collection;

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Set how much product should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @param $count
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New
     */
    public function setProductsCount($count)
    {
        $this->_productsCount = $count;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPartDiagram()
    {
        if ($this->getId()) {
            return Mage::getModel('pws_productpartsdiagram/productpartsdiagram')->load($this->getId());
        }

        if (Mage::registry('product')) {
            $collection = Mage::getModel('pws_productpartsdiagram/productpartsdiagram')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('sku', Mage::registry('product')->getSku());
            return $collection->getFirstItem();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get how much products should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsCount()
    {
        if (null === $this->_productsCount) {
            $this->_productsCount = self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT;
        }
        return $this->_productsCount;
    }


    public function getItemCollection()
    {
        return $this->_itemCollection;
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_items)) {
            $this->_items = $this->getItemCollection()->getItems();
        }
        return $this->_items;
    }

    public function getRowCount()
    {
        return ceil(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())/$this->getColumnCount());
    }

    public function setColumnCount($columns)
    {
        if (intval($columns) > 0) {
            $this->_columnCount = intval($columns);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getColumnCount()
    {
        return $this->_columnCount;
    }

    public function resetItemsIterator()
    {
        $this->getItems();
        reset($this->_items);
    }

    public function getIterableItem()
    {
        $item = current($this->_items);
        next($this->_items);
        return $item;
    }

    /**
     * Set how many items we need to show in block
     * Notice: this parametr will be also applied
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @param int $limit
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell
     */
    public function setItemLimit($type, $limit)
    {
        if (intval($limit) > 0) {
            $this->_itemLimits[$type] = intval($limit);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getItemLimit($type = '')
    {
        if ($type == '') {
            return $this->_itemLimits;
        }
        if (isset($this->_itemLimits[$type])) {
            return $this->_itemLimits[$type];
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want access to the collection of diagrams. So it might be simplest to add this code to your product `view.phtml` file:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('pws_productpartsdiagram/productpartsdiagram')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('sku', Mage::registry('product')->getSku());

foreach($collection as $productpartsdiagram){

      //code to display each diagram

}
```

Alternatively extend the class which has public function getPartDiagram() in it and add your own function:

```
public function getPartDiagramsAll()
    {

        if (Mage::registry('product')) {
            $collection = Mage::getModel('pws_productpartsdiagram/productpartsdiagram')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('sku', Mage::registry('product')->getSku());
            return $collection;
        }

    return null;
}
```

Call this function, then loop over the returned collection.